# Enumerate a string in Elixir

Tags: string, elixir, enumeration

In Elixir, if I have a string such as `"José1 José2"`, how do I enumerate it? If I try to use `Enum` or `for` comprehensions, I get the following error:

> ** (Protocol.UndefinedError) protocol Enumerable not implemented for "José1 José2" of type BitString

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Strings in Elixir are UTF-8 encoded binaries. If you want to enumerate a binary, which is just a collection of bytes, you need to specify how.

[`String.graphemes/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/String.html#graphemes/1) - this will give you a list of strings, where each string contains an individual Unicode grapheme. This is probably closest to what you mean if you want each "character".

```elixir
iex> String.graphemes("José1 José2")
["J", "o", "s", "é", "1", " ", "J", "o", "s", "é", "2"]
```

[`String.codepoints/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/String.html#codepoints/1) - this will give you a list of strings broken down by Unicode codepoints. Note that a Unicode codepoint does not necessarily translate to a human-readable character.

```elixir
iex> String.codepoints("José1 José2")
["J", "o", "s", "é", "1", " ", "J", "o", "s", "e", "́", "2"]
```

You can see that the first and the second `é` *graphemes* are represented differently in terms of unicode codepoints. The first one is `LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE (U+00E9)`, whereas the second one is `LATIN SMALL LETTER E (U+0065)` followed by `COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT (U+0301)`.

This is why you can't simply enumerate a string, because when dealing with Unicode, you have to specify whether you are interested in graphemes, or codepoints, or something else.

[`String.to_charlist/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/String.html#to_charlist/1) - gives you a list of the numerical Unicode codepoints of the string. This is can be used to interface with Erlang libraries that use this format.

```elixir
iex> String.to_charlist("José1 José2")
[74, 111, 115, 233, 49, 32, 74, 111, 115, 101, 769, 50]
```

[`:binary.bin_to_list/1`](https://erlang.org/doc/man/binary.html#bin_to_list-1) -  If you just want to enumerate the bytes.

```elixir
iex> :binary.bin_to_list("José1 José2")
[74, 111, 115, 195, 169, 49, 32, 74, 111, 115, 101, 204, 129, 50]
```

---

Once you have a list, you can Enumerate it using  comprehensions or any of the functions in the [`Enum`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html) module:

```elixir
iex> for c <- String.graphemes("José1 José2"), into: "", do: c <> c
"JJoosséé11  JJoosséé22"

iex> "José1 José2" |> String.graphemes() |> Enum.join("|")
"J|o|s|é|1| |J|o|s|é|2"
```

---

It is also possible to use [comprehensions](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#for/1) with bitstring generators for enumerating the bytes and codepoints (but not the graphemes).

Equivalent to `:binary.bin_to_list/1`:

```elixir
iex> for <<byte <- "José1 José2">>, do: byte
[74, 111, 115, 195, 169, 49, 32, 74, 111, 115, 101, 204, 129, 50]
```

Equivalent to `String.to_charlist/1`, by specifying the [type](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#%3C%3C%3E%3E/1-types) of the binary is `utf8`:

```elixir
iex> for <<cp::utf8 <- "José1 José2">>, do: cp
[74, 111, 115, 233, 49, 32, 74, 111, 115, 101, 769, 50]
```

Equivalent to `String.codepoints/1`, by specifying the type of the binary is `utf8`, and converting the resulting codepoints back to UTF-8 binaries:

```elixir
iex> for <<cp::utf8 <- "José1 José2">>, do: <<cp::utf8>>
["J", "o", "s", "é", "1", " ", "J", "o", "s", "e", "́", "2"]
```

---

P.S. For further reading about character encodings, this blog post from 2003 is great: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/).