# guard to check each character in the string

Tags: elixir

My function takes a string and I need to check each individual character is either "0" or "1".
How to do that?
I have tried this:

```
  defguard is_bit_string(str)
           when is_binary(str) and
                  byte_size(str) == 1 and
                  binary_part(str, 0, 1) in ["0", "1"]

  defguard is_bit_string(str)
           # byte_size(str) == 1 and
           when is_binary(str) and
                  binary_part(str, 0, 1) in ["0", "1"] and
                  is_bit_string(binary_part(str, 1, byte_size(str) - 1))
```

But turns out gaurd can't be recursive(ig as i get following error:

```
(CompileError) cannot find or invoke local is_bit_string/1 inside guards. Only macros can be invoked in a guards and they must be defined before their invocation. Called as: is_bit_string(binary_part(str, 1, byte_size(str) - 1))
```

The problem with checking this inside the function body is I need to check this for multiple functions so it will just be unwanted repition. Are there other ways so that I don't need to do this inside every function?

Comment: Why does your API use binary text strings rather than actual bitstrings?

Answer (score 3):

I will propose using this function instead:

```
def is_bit_string?(str) when is_binary(str) do
  str
  |> String.graphemes()
  |> Enum.all?(fn c -> c in ["0","1"] end)
end

def is_bit_string?(_), do: false
```

Comment: Don't use `String.split` to enumerate a string. Check out [Enumerate a string in Elixir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67791728/enumerate-a-string-in-elixir).

Comment: Thanks, replaced with String.graphemes()