# How are these two comprehensions different?

Tags: elixir

I'm new to Elixir (programming in general too) and I don't understand what about Elixir is enabling the interpretation between string and ASCII here.

```
result = for << n <- "abc132" >>, do: n + 1
IO.puts(result) #bcd243 - I assume this converts to ASCII and then back to string

string = "abc123"
for n <- String.to_charlist(string) do
    IO.puts(n+1) #98,99,100,50,51,52 - this converts to ASCII, but doesn't convert back to string?
end
```

Comment: See also [Enumerate a string in Elixir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67791728/enumerate-a-string-in-elixir).

Answer (score 4):

> IO.puts(result) #bcd243 - I assume this converts to ASCII and then
> back to string

Your two examples are equivalent to the following:

```
iex(14)> IO.puts [97, 98, 99]
abc
:ok

iex(15)> IO.puts 97
97
:ok

iex(16)> IO.puts 98
98
:ok

iex(17)> IO.puts 99 
99
:ok
```

`for()` returns a list:

```
iex(5)> result = for << n <- "abc132" >>, do: n
'abc132'   <<<====******
```

Note the single quotes.  Single quotes denote a charlist, where a charlist is a list of integers. In fact, a charlist such as `'abc'` is merely a shortcut for writing `[97,98,99]`:

```
iex(13)> 'abc' === [97,98,99]
true
```

Take a moment to let that sink in.  You must come to the realizaton that there is no difference between writing `'abc'` and `[97,98,99]` in your code.

A source of much confusion is that `IO.puts()` displays the same thing for charlists and strings:

```
iex(6)> IO.puts 'abc132'
abc132
:ok

iex(23)> IO.puts [97,98,99,49,50,51]
abc123
:ok

iex(7)> IO.puts "abc132"
abc132
:ok
```

That is really, really unhelpful when you are doing some math, for example: say you gather some student test scores in a list and you want to display the test scores before calculating their average, and the test scores happen to be `[97,98,99]` and for output you see `abc` instead of `[97,98,99]`.  You will probably tear some hair out trying to figure out what the hell is going on.

Looking at the output from `IO.puts` can be very confusing. To determine what something really is, use `IO.inspect` rather than `IO.puts`:

```
iex(1)> result = 'abc'         
'abc'

iex(2)> IO.puts result    
abc
:ok

iex(3)> IO.inspect result
'abc'
'abc'
```

You can go one step further and configure iex to display charlists for what they really are, i.e. lists of integers:

```
iex(4)> IEx.configure(inspect: [charlists: :as_lists])
:ok

iex(5)> IO.inspect result                             
'abc'
[97, 98, 99]
```

You can even create a `.iex.exs` file to automatically set that configuration every time iex launches.

Next, when you use the following generator in your `for()`:

```
<< n <- "abc132" >>
```

each `n` is an integer, which represents one byte in the double quoted string.  The characters in your string all have a one byte integer code, but for characters that are represented by multiple byte integer codes, such as "Latin Capital Letter A WITH TILDE": Ã, `n` will be only one byte of the UTF-8 integer code:

```
iex(5)> str = "\xC3\x83"                
"Ã"

iex(6)>  for << n <- str >>, do: IO.puts n
195
131
[:ok, :ok]
```

In your second example:

```
string = "abc123"
for n <- String.to_charlist(string) do
    IO.puts(n+1) #98,99,100,50,51,52 - this converts to ASCII, but doesn't convert back to string?
end
```

you convert the string to a charlist:

```
String.to_charlist(string)
```

and as mentioned before a charlist is a list of integers.  Therefore, your generator becomes:

```
n <- [97,98,99,49,50,51]
```

where each `n` is one of the integers in the list. Then you use `IO.puts` on an integer plus 1, which is displayed as an integer:

```
iex(3)> n = 97
97

iex(4)> IO.puts n
97
:ok

iex(5)> IO.puts n+1
98
:ok
```

When you give `IO.puts` a single integer, it outputs the integer.

In the second example, you never use the list returned by the `for()`, but because `IO.puts()` returns `:ok` for each `n`, the returned list consists solely of `:ok`'s.

To sum up, in both your examples the generators return the same integers, but in your first example you use `IO.puts` on the whole result list, which is displayed as a string; and in the second example you use `IO.puts` on the individual integers.

Answer (score 2):

Elixir has two different representations of strings (as does Erlang).  The default Elixir [String](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/String.html) is a UTF-8-encoded Erlang `binary` object; a "charlist" is literally a list of characters.

An important technical note here is that the string is UTF-8-encoded Unicode and not necessarily ASCII.  If your string contains only ASCII characters then it is ASCII, but you can't guarantee this in general.  It's very possible that the binary will contain multiple bytes corresponding to a single character.  For example, you can write out by hand U+00A0 NO-BREAK SPACE

```
iex> <<0xc2, 0xa0>>
" "
iex> <<0xc2, 0xa0>> |> String.length()
1
```

which is two bytes but one character.

In your second loop, you've converted the string to a list of code points, and then manipulating the code points.  Since the alternate string representation is a *list* of code points, you can wrap each code point in a list

```
for n <- String.to_charlist(string) do
    IO.puts([n+1]) # creating a single-character charlist-format string
end
```

but since a charlist is a list, you can also manipulate it using normal functional techniques as well.

```
iex> string |>
...>   String.to_charlist() |>
...>   Enum.map(fn c -> c + 1 end) |>
...>   to_string()
"bcd234"
```

This last form doesn't specifically depend on the string being ASCII.